# Changed disk label : caused Visual Studio to be unusable

Tags: visual-studio, ide

Today I had to rename a local disk drive from B to D. Visual studio was installed on the same drive. After I renamed it Visual studio couldn't open again. Whenever I try to uninstall/repair/modify it says "  Fatal error during installation.
 " . Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is the following : Change the disk label back to the previous one (in my case that was B) and then uninstall VS, then install again on the newly labeled disk drive.